# Python Boto: how to run 100 T1 Micro instances?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Basically I have python Selenium tests using Chromedriver.

I want to run parallel tests. Would AWS T1 Micro-instances be enough?

Say I want to launch 100 parallel test, how can I achieve this with Python Boto? Is this the right tool to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very open-ended.  If the specific question is "Can I launch 100 t1.micro instances with boto?" then the answer is, sure.  Like this:

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever region you prefer
c.run_instances(image_id='ami-12345678',  # use your preferred AMI here
                key_name='my_key',
                security_groups=['my_sec_group'],
                instance_type='t1.micro',
                min_count=100, max_count=100)
```

This will either launch 100 instances or not launch any.  The hard part begins now.  You have to figure out how to get all of your instances to perform the test that you wish to perform.  That part is beyond the scope of boto.

Comment: also, depending on the AWS account, your maximum number of ec2 instances may be restricted, you will need to request a limit increase from AWS support.